# Displaying Menu Option Status if Selected on Console Application

Tags: c++, menu, console-application

I am new to C++ and I am trying to create a console application that has a menu with options and with
a status of weither or not the option is selected.

Here is the sample code that I am working with:

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <Windows.h>

int main()
{
    //Create Console Layout
    std::cout << "--------------------------------------------------\n";
    std::cout << "                  Console Menu                    \n";
    std::cout << "               Subtitle for Menu                  \n";
    std::cout << "--------------------------------------------------\n";

    //Targeted Game for Hacking (Insert Game Title)
    std::cout << "\nAuthor: John Doe\n";
    //Game Status
    std::cout << "APP STATUS:\t\t\t" << "->" << "OFF" << "<-\n";
    std::cout << "[NUMPAD1] Option 1\t\t" << "->" << "OFF" << "<-\n";
    std::cout << "[NUMPAD2] Option 2\t\t" << "->" << "OFF" << "<-\n";
    std::cout << "[NUMPAD3] Option 3\t\t" << "->" << "OFF" << "<-\n";
    std::cout << "[NUMPAD4] Option 4\t\t" << "->" << "OFF" << "<-\n";
    std::cout << "[NUMPAD5] Option 5\t\t" << "->" << "OFF" << "<-\n";
    std::cout << "[NUMPAD6] Option 6\t\t" << "->" << "OFF" << "<-\n";
    std::cout << "[NUMPAD7] Option 7\t\t" << "->" << "OFF" << "<-\n";
    std::cout << "[NUMPAD8] Option 8\t\t" << "->" << "OFF" << "<-\n";
    std::cout << "[INSERT]  Exit\n";
    std::cout << "--------------------------------------------------\n";
    return 0;
}
```

I know that I probably need to write a loop that checks the see if an option is selected or not and maybe store that value as a bool and then have a string display OFF or ON in the menu?

Please pardon my lack of programing knowledge but I am new :-) look forward to your guys comments!

Comment: You can use _std:cin_ for this but the user will have to press enter key to submit the input. 

std::string input;
std::cin>>input;

Comment: Sandeep, thanks for the reply! I also came up with one soultion in that of the "App connected" portion I wrote this code: std::cout << "APP STATUS:\t\t\t\t";
        if (bappStatus == true)
        {
            std::cout << "->ON<-\n";
        }
        else {
            std::cout << "->OFF<-\n";
        }